# do not load external .js files using react-router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm designing a creact-react-app with the react-router-dom library, but I'm using external resources (css, js) that are called from the index.html. When creating a routing and navigating from one component to another do not load external js files

Comment: Alex, do you mean you only want to load things when you need them, not all at once (also known as Lazy Loading)?

Comment: not really, but those files are part of a template and the js files contain jquery. but they do not load after the first page and I have to refresh the page to load

Comment: So you're saying that you have dependencies that load in index.html as part of a template, but those dependencies are not available in your React components?

Comment: exactly, they are independent files

Comment: When jquery is loaded from index.html it attaches to window, so in your component you would use window.jQuery, this is assuming you have no control over the template. Otherwise you should remove jQuery from index.html, add jQuery through npm, and import it like any other module when you need it. Also keep in mind you should not be using jQuery in your render methods (accessing the DOM)

Comment: I have a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642283/running-jquery-scripts-on-react-router-redirect