# Running jquery scripts on react router redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am looking to port my existing website that uses a theme to utilise react components.

The theme has a lot of functions that makes the UI render properly (including several animations).

The theme's js imports a lot of other js libraries.

This means that there is no way for me to write the react version of whatever UI elements that the theme provides.

However, the actually elements can be used as 'dumb components' and I dont need any data bound functionality from them.

I can import my js libraries' dependencies in my `public/html` folder so thats not a big issue.

The real issue is my theme's library (which I will call scripts.js) not getting loaded every time there is a redirect using `react-router`.

Since `react-router` doesnt actually reload the page, there is no way for my `scripts.js` to know when to do its UI functions.

[This discussion here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3256)
talks about wrapping the `scripts.js` in a function and calling it every time an on update happens at the `Router` level.

Since react-router 4 doesnt have `onUpdate` , I decided to subscribe to the history.
I am doing that like so:

```javascript
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';


const history = createBrowserHistory();
history.listen(() => {
    console.log("url has changed");
});

export {history};
```

Now I am able to know every time a route change happens, all I need now is to actually get the `scripts.js` to 'load'.

My `scripts.js` is very long and some of it is proprietary , so I will only post a snippet of it here.

```javascript
mr = (function (mr, $, window, document){
    "use strict";

    mr = mr || {};

    var components = {documentReady: [],documentReadyDeferred: [], windowLoad: [], windowLoadDeferred: []};

    mr.status = {documentReadyRan: false, windowLoadPending: false};

    $(document).ready(documentReady);
    $(window).on("load", windowLoad);

    function documentReady(context){

        context = typeof context === typeof undefined ? $ : context;
        components.documentReady.concat(components.documentReadyDeferred).forEach(function(component){
            component(context);
        });
        mr.status.documentReadyRan = true;
        if(mr.status.windowLoadPending){
            windowLoad(mr.setContext());
        }
    }

    function windowLoad(context){
        if(mr.status.documentReadyRan){
            mr.status.windowLoadPending = false;
            context = typeof context === "object" ? $ : context;
            components.windowLoad.concat(components.windowLoadDeferred).forEach(function(component){
               component(context);
            });
        }else{
            mr.status.windowLoadPending = true;
        }
    }

    mr.setContext = function (contextSelector){
        var context = $;
        if(typeof contextSelector !== typeof undefined){
            return function(selector){
                return $(contextSelector).find(selector);
            };
        }
        return context;
    };

    mr.components    = components;
    mr.documentReady = documentReady;
    mr.windowLoad    = windowLoad;

    return mr;
}(window.mr, jQuery, window, document));
```

Another bit :

```javascript
//////////////// Scroll Functions
mr = (function (mr, $, window, document){
    "use strict";


    mr.scroll           = {};
    var raf             = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    mr.scroll.listeners = [];
    mr.scroll.busy      = false;
    mr.scroll.y         = 0;
    mr.scroll.x         = 0;

    var documentReady = function($){

        //////////////// Capture Scroll Event and fire scroll function
        jQuery(window).off('scroll.mr');    
        jQuery(window).on('scroll.mr', function(evt) {
                if(mr.scroll.busy === false){

                    mr.scroll.busy = true;
                    raf(function(evt){  
                        mr.scroll.update(evt);
                    });

                }
                if(evt.stopPropagation){
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                }
        });

    };

    mr.scroll.update = function(event){

        // Loop through all mr scroll listeners
        var parallax = typeof window.mr_parallax !== typeof undefined ? true : false;
        mr.scroll.y = (parallax ? mr_parallax.mr_getScrollPosition() : window.pageYOffset);
        mr.scroll.busy = false;
        if(parallax){
            mr_parallax.mr_parallaxBackground();
        }


        if(mr.scroll.listeners.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0, l = mr.scroll.listeners.length; i < l; i++) {
               mr.scroll.listeners[i](event);
            }
        }

    };

    mr.scroll.documentReady = documentReady;

    mr.components.documentReady.push(documentReady);

    return mr;

}(mr, jQuery, window, document));
```

I am not well versed with the way these libraries are compiled from web pack to the browser, so sorry if the code block was inadequate/unnecessary

My question is, how do I make sure my script is loaded every time a `react-router`page change happens.

Comment: Hi, this was a long time ago, but I would like to know if you solve it and how?

Comment: no, unfortunately there is no single solution that solves this. react requires knowledge of state updates, and jQuery does not have such a restriction. as such it is not feasible to run arbitrary jquery in react